# How to use lower version of rails if higher version has already use in other app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

During creation of a e-commerce application using spree gems, I faced the problem that spree is not compatible with rails 5.

So i have to use the lower version of rails for this e-commerce application and also rails 5 for other.

How will i resolve the issue?

Comment: If you need to use a package which requires rails 5, then you also need to use rails 5. That's how dependencies work. Your options include (1) upgrading to rails 5 (2) not using the package which introduces the rails 5 dependency, or downgrading the package to a version which didn't have the dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Running different applications that use different versions of rails (or any other dependency) is  not a problem. This is the point of bundler: each application's Gemfile lists the gems it needs and their versions.

Comment: I don't know spree, but isn't it a rails engine? If so, bundler can't help here?

Comment: @sergio Perhaps i am misreading the question. I interpreted it as one app is a rails 5 app, another, separate app uses spree